# Adding reactions to specific message ID within loop

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to react and remove react to a message that is always in the channel. In my code below I'm trying to get the message by its ID and then react to it then remove reaction on a loop. I'm getting the following error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<react() done, defined at c:/Users/test/Desktop/test bot/test.py:161> exception=InvalidArgument('message argument must be a Message',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/test/Desktop/test bot/test.py", line 167, in react
    await client.add_reaction(msg, emoji1)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 949, in add_reaction
    raise InvalidArgument('message argument must be a Message')
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: message argument must be a Message
Test Bot Online.
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ServerDisconnectedError()>
aiohttp.errors.ServerDisconnectedError
```

---

```
client = discord.Client()
async def react():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel("479919577279758111")
    while not client.is_closed:
        msg =  get(client.get_message(channel,'505306270891507712'))
        emoji1 = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='gsmile')
        await client.add_reaction(msg, emoji1)
        await client.remove_reaction(msg, emoji1)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

@client.event
client.loop.create_task(react())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
msg = get(client.get_message(channel,'505306270891507712'))
```

May be where your problem is.

```
msg = client.get_message(channel,'505306270891507712')
```

is sufficient to get the `Message` object.  You're also adding a reaction and then immediately removing it.  I'm not sure if that's what you intended.

You also need to pass your `Member` object to `remove_reaction`:

```
await client.remove_reaction(msg, emoji1, channel.server.me)
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but for some reason, it's still not grabbing the message or doesn't think the message exists. I get the following error. 

`Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<react() done, defined at C:\Users\test\Desktop\test.py:25> exception=InvalidArgument('message argument must be a Message',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\test.py", line 31, in react
    await client.add_reaction(msg, emoji1)`

Comment: `File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 949, in add_reaction
    raise InvalidArgument('message argument must be a Message')
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: message argument must be a Message
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ServerDisconnectedError()>
aiohttp.errors.ServerDisconnectedError`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can not add reactions with the name, you have to put the code or the actual emoji. You also do not need `@client.event` above the task creation.